# NSInternalInconsistencyException error

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am having issues switching between view controllers.

My md360AppDelegate.h header looks like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class md360ViewController;
@interface md360AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) md360ViewController *viewController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@end
```

and my md360AppDelegate.m implementation looks like this.

```
#import "md360AppDelegate.h"
#import "md360ViewController.h"

@implementation md360AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[md360ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"md360ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.window setRootViewController:self.navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

i am creating an instance of UINavigationController and storing it in navigationController property of this class.

I want to change the ViewController when a user click on a button in md360ViewController.

My md360ViewController.h looks like this.

```
@interface md360ViewController : UIViewController
@property IBOutlet UIButton *homePathwayBtn;
@property IBOutlet UIButton *homeDiseaseBtn;
@property IBOutlet UIButton *homePipelineBtn;
- (IBAction)homeButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

and my implementation looks something like

```
#import "md360ViewController.h"
#import "md360AppDelegate.h"
#import "pipeViewDisease.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

    - (IBAction)homeButton:(id)sender {
        UIViewController *pipeViewDisease = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"pipeViewDiease" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:pipeViewDisease animated:YES];
    }
```

and when i click on UIButton the application crash with following message.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in
>   bundle: 'NSBundle 
>   (loaded)' with name 'pipeViewDiease''

what could be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably* just a misspelled NIB name:

```
initWithNibName:@"pipeViewDiease"
```

should be:

```
initWithNibName:@"pipeViewDisease"
                            ^
```

Comment: @IbrahimAzharArmar It happens.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it's a spelling mistake (should be pipeViewDisease), this error usually occurs when files are re-named outside of the xCode environment.

To fix this:

- remove the file in question from the project
- re-import the files to your project.